# scrapy CONCURRENT_REQUESTS ignored when DOWNLOAD_DELAY set?

Tags: python, scrapy

Looking at the scrapy stats (`Crawled X pages (at X pages/min)`) seems to me that as soon as, e.g.:

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 4.5
```

is set the requests become sequential no matter what the `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` setting is.

From my understanding, shouldn't the delay count for each concurrent request or did I misinterpret the scrapy architecture? So in my example shouldn't:

```
scrapy crawl us_al -a cid_range=000001..000020
```

run faster with 10 concurrent requests and not in approximately 1 minute and 50 seconds (keeping in mind `RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY`), which it does for me? How would I change that behavior? When there is no `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` querying 20 items with `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 5` takes 4 seconds and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1` 10 seconds a behavior which makes more sense to me.

Here is how the spider looks like:

```
import random
import re
import scrapy

class UsAlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "us_al"
    allowed_domains = ["arc-sos.state.al.us"]
    start_urls = []
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 10,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 10,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 4.5
    }

    def __init__(self, cid_range=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Range (in the form: 000001..000010)
        """
        super(UsAlSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.cid_range = cid_range

    def start_requests(self):
        if self.cid_range and not re.search(r'^\d+\.\.\d+$', self.cid_range):
            self.logger.error('Check input parameter cid_range={} needs to be in form cid_range=000001..000010'.format(self.cid_range))
            return
        # crawl according to input option
        id_range = self.cid_range.split('..')
        shuffled_ids = ["{0:06}".format(i) for i in xrange(
            int(id_range[0]), int(id_range[1]) + 1)]
        random.shuffle(shuffled_ids)
        for id_ in shuffled_ids:
            yield self.make_requests_from_url('http://arc-sos.state.al.us/cgi/corpdetail.mbr/detail?corp={}'.format(id_))

    def parse(self, response):
        # parse the page info
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` is just a way to hold requests in general, so if you are using any other settings (which are usually enforced by domain), there is no problem on setting `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` to a high number.

The `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` is used by domain which is correct as the idea behind it is to not hit hard a specific website. this also affects the `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`, as if `DOWNLOAD_DELAY>0 -> CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN=1`.

Comment: So `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` counts for all spiders and is a general setting for the whole scrapy framework?