# CONCURRENT_REQUESTS doesn't make more requests

Tags: python, scrapy

I've added in scrapy settings:

`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 8` and `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1`

So I should have 8*60 scraped pages per minute. But, scrapy behaves like `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1`. It scrapes only 60 pages per minute.

`scrapy bench`:

```
2018-11-05 22:38:03 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 7 pages (at 60 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

telnet `localthost:6023`:

```
time()-engine.start_time                        : 22.815539360046387
engine.has_capacity()                           : False
len(engine.downloader.active)                   : 16
engine.scraper.is_idle()                        : False
engine.spider.name                              : historic
engine.spider_is_idle(engine.spider)            : False
engine.slot.closing                             : False
len(engine.slot.inprogress)                     : 16
len(engine.slot.scheduler.dqs or [])            : 0
len(engine.slot.scheduler.mqs)                  : 49
len(engine.scraper.slot.queue)                  : 0
len(engine.scraper.slot.active)                 : 0
engine.scraper.slot.active_size                 : 0
engine.scraper.slot.itemproc_size               : 0
engine.scraper.slot.needs_backout()             : False
```

No matter how many `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` I'm adding, nothing is changing.

I have no clue how to make scrapy faster. How can I start more `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`? What is the reason for this situation?

Comment: have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461327/scrapy-concurrent-requests-ignored-when-download-delay-set

Comment: I've looked there. Still don't have a answer ;)

Comment: I have to have speed at least 600 pages/min. Do you know how to do it using scrapy?

Comment: it depends on what the site you are scraping is capable of delivering. If there server is slow or maybe ratelimiting your requests, you won't be able to achieve your goal anyway. Probably decreasing `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25` and/or increasing `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` might help.